# objective-c UINavigationController +UITabbarcontroller

Tags: objective-c

[This Pickture is black out screen but build success...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW67p.png)

My application have UINavigationCOntroller and UITabbarController.
However,secondViewController is black on the display!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//2 UIViewControllerの生成
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
NoteFunction *noteFunction = [[NoteFunction alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];




//3 UINavigationControllerの生成
navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
navigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:noteFunction];

//4 NavigationControllerを配列にしてまとめる
navi = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController1,navigationController3,nil];
//5 tabbarcontrollerの生成
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:navi animated:NO];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

noteFunction.title = @"ノート";

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement,I will give sample coding.This is the exact solution

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
   // Override point for customization after application launch.

   FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *firstNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstVC];

   SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *secondNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: secondVC];

   ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *thirdNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: thirdVC];

   NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [tabViewControllers addObject:firstNavVC];
   [tabViewControllers addObject:secondNavVC];
   [tabViewControllers addObject:thirdNavVC];

   firstNavVC.tabBarItem =
   [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"First", nil)
                              image:nil
                                tag:1];

   secondNavVC.tabBarItem =
   [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Second", nil)
                              image:nil
                                tag:2];
   thirdNavVC.tabBarItem =
   [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Third", nil)
                              image:nil
                                tag:3];

   UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
   tabbarController.viewControllers = tabViewControllers;

   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
   self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;

   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this program!

I write this code in "Note Function.h"

```
(void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"Called!ViewDidLoad");
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from    a nib.}
}
```

Comment: Yasi if my answer is helpful for you please give up vote or up vote my answer.It seems to be so helpful for others it they refer your question.